# Not able to load data in druid cluster setup

Tags: druid

I'm getting this error while loading some data in druid cluster. I have the machine with the specified memory. Can someone suggest me with any solution? I'm doing a stream load, also I'm not able to load batch data.
These are the machines I'm using.

1.) 4 vCPUs
15 GB RAM
80 GB SSD storage

2.) 8 vCPUs
61 GB RAM
160 GB SSD storage

3.) 8 vCPUs
61 GB RAM
160 GB SSD storage

```
{
  "dataSource" : "metrics",
  "task" : "index_realtime_metrics_2019-01-15T09:00:00.000Z_0_0",
  "status" : "TaskFailed"
}
2019-01-15 09:14:39,520 [Hashed wheel timer #1] INFO  c.metamx.emitter.core.LoggingEmitter - Event [{"feed":"alerts","timestamp":"2019-01-15T09:14:39.520Z","service":"
tranquility","host":"localhost","severity":"anomaly","description":"Loss of Druid redundancy: metrics","data":{"dataSource":"metrics","task":"index_realtime_metrics_20
19-01-15T09:00:00.000Z_0_0","status":"TaskFailed"}}]
2019-01-15 09:14:39,521 [Hashed wheel timer #1] WARN  c.m.tranquility.beam.ClusteredBeam - Emitting alert: [anomaly] Beam defunct: druid:overlord/metrics
{
  "eventCount" : 1,
  "timestamp" : "2019-01-15T09:00:00.000Z",
  "beam" : "MergingPartitioningBeam(DruidBeam(interval = 2019-01-15T09:00:00.000Z/2019-01-15T10:00:00.000Z, partition = 0, tasks = [index_realtime_metrics_2019-01-15T0
9:00:00.000Z_0_0/metrics-009-0000-0000]))"
}
com.metamx.tranquility.beam.DefunctBeamException: Tasks are all gone: index_realtime_metrics_2019-01-15T09:00:00.000Z_0_0
        at com.metamx.tranquility.druid.DruidBeam$$anonfun$sendAll$2$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(DruidBeam.scala:115) ~[io.druid.tranquility-core-0.8.0.jar:0.8.0
]
        at com.metamx.tranquility.druid.DruidBeam$$anonfun$sendAll$2$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(DruidBeam.scala:115) ~[io.druid.tranquility-core-0.8.0.jar:0.8.0
]
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
        at com.metamx.tranquility.druid.DruidBeam$$anonfun$sendAll$2$$anonfun$6.apply(DruidBeam.scala:112) ~[io.druid.tranquility-core-0.8.0.jar:0.8.0]
        at com.metamx.tranquility.druid.DruidBeam$$anonfun$sendAll$2$$anonfun$6.apply(DruidBeam.scala:109) ~[io.druid.tranquility-core-0.8.0.jar:0.8.0]
        at com.twitter.util.Future$$anonfun$map$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Future.scala:950) ~[com.twitter.util-core_2.11-6.30.0.jar:6.30.0]
        at com.twitter.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:13) ~[com.twitter.util-core_2.11-6.30.0.jar:6.30.0]
        at com.twitter.util.Future$.apply(Future.scala:97) ~[com.twitter.util-core_2.11-6.30.0.jar:6.30.0]
        at com.twitter.util.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:950) ~[com.twitter.util-core_2.11-6.30.0.jar:6.30.0]
        at com.twitter.util.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:949) ~[com.twitter.util-core_2.11-6.30.0.jar:6.30.0]
        at com.twitter.util.Promise$Transformer.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:112) ~[com.twitter.util-core_2.11-6.30.0.jar:6.30.0]
        at com.twitter.util.Promise$Transformer.k(Promise.scala:112) ~[com.twitter.util-core_2.11-6.30.0.jar:6.30.0]
        at com.twitter.util.Promise$Transformer.apply(Promise.scala:122) ~[com.twitter.util-core_2.11-6.30.0.jar:6.30.0]
        at com.twitter.util.Promise$Transformer.apply(Promise.scala:103) ~[com.twitter.util-core_2.11-6.30.0.jar:6.30.0]
        at com.twitter.util.Promise$$anon$1.run(Promise.scala:366) ~[com.twitter.util-core_2.11-6.30.0.jar:6.30.0]
        at com.twitter.concurrent.LocalScheduler$Activation.run(Scheduler.scala:178) [com.twitter.util-core_2.11-6.30.0.jar:6.30.0]
        at com.twitter.concurrent.LocalScheduler$Activation.submit(Scheduler.scala:136) [com.twitter.util-core_2.11-6.30.0.jar:6.30.0]
        at com.twitter.concurrent.LocalScheduler.submit(Scheduler.scala:207) [com.twitter.util-core_2.11-6.30.0.jar:6.30.0]
        at com.twitter.concurrent.Scheduler$.submit(Scheduler.scala:92) [com.twitter.util-core_2.11-6.30.0.jar:6.30.0]
        at com.twitter.util.Promise.runq(Promise.scala:350) [com.twitter.util-core_2.11-6.30.0.jar:6.30.0]
        at com.twitter.util.Promise.updateIfEmpty(Promise.scala:726) [com.twitter.util-core_2.11-6.30.0.jar:6.30.0]
        at com.twitter.util.Promise.link(Promise.scala:793) [com.twitter.util-core_2.11-6.30.0.jar:6.30.0]
        at com.twitter.util.Promise.become(Promise.scala:658) [com.twitter.util-core_2.11-6.30.0.jar:6.30.0]
:
```

Answer (score 1):

can you share the **indexing task logs**?

according to: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/druid-user/yZEnAk0iKr4 and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/druid-user/ZBTU08VNp2o it might be lack of memory in the middlemanager

Comment: I followed these links after that we increased our machine size according to the druid site.